# Dojo dateTextBox onChange only after valid constraints have passed

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo DateTextBox that looks like this:

```
<input
dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
dojoAttachPoint="axisStart"
dojoAttachEvent="onChange:_onChange"
data-dojo-props="constraints:{min: new Date(1990,01,01)}"
tabIndex="2" />
```

If I use the date picker to go back before 1990, I can't as they are striked out. Expected.

However, if I manually type the date to be anything before 1990 and then leave the inuput field, the onChange event still fires. I don't want it to.

The dojo alert does display "This value is out of range" correctly.

Is there a way I can have the onChange event fire only if the constraints are met? Or is there  a property I can look for in the _onChange function in order not to run the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching the issue from the wrong angle, it should change because the value of the dijit does change.

You can check if the widget is valid by calling the _isValid() function of the dijit. Could it be that you need to do somthing like the following:

```
dijit.on('change', function(e){
    if (dijit._isValid()){
        //run some code
    }
});
```